# Assign Img Class in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created the following function for using ACF to collect images that will be used as background images on a homepage. There will be a different image for each day of the week. I'd like to use lazyload for the images, but I don't know how to assign an image class in this scenario.  Grateful for any suggestions.

```
function my_custom_background() {

if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
    return;
}

$img_id = get_field( strtolower( date( 'l' ) ) );

echo "<style>\n";

// Large desktops.

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'large_desktop_background' );


echo "body {\n";
echo sprintf( "\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "}\n";


// Small desktops.


$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'small_desktop_background' );


echo "@media (max-width: 1199px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";


// Tablets.

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'tablet_background' );


echo "@media (max-width: 991px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";

// Mobile.

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'phone_background' );


echo "@media (max-width: 767px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";

echo "</style>\n";


}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_background' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filter to add classes to the body tag.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    return array_merge( $classes, array( 'class-name' ) );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That was perfect.

Comment: Accept the answer when you get a moment.  You're welcome :)